# Do multiple Speed weapons grant multiple extra attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I was asked by a player if [Speed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/speed) weapons granted an extra attack per speed weapon. So if a player dual wields speed weapons do they get two extra attacks.

I have always interpreted the rules of speed that they do grant an extra attack each but do not stack with haste and the like.

I have found multiple forum based discussions but they are all opinion based. Is there an official ruling on whether or not Speed weapons stack, or is this one of those things that is open to interpretation on a DM to DM basis?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a ruling by James Jacobs in the ["Ask James Jacobs ALL your Questions"](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=344?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#17175) post the on the paizo messageboards.

> **James Jacobs** Creative Director
>
> > 1. If a creature dual-wields two Speed weapons, does the creature gain one additional attack total on a full attack, or one attack per weapon of speed on a full attack?
> >        [...]
>
> 1) No... speed effects, whether they come from multiple speed weapons or multiple haste spells or any combination of the two, do not stack. You can only ever gain 1 additional attack from a haste effect in a round.

With James Jacobs being the single topmost man directly responsible for Pathfinder, this thread is pretty much as official as it gets with Pathfinder rulings, falling just short of the official FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

From the [PRD itself](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/weapons.html):

> **Speed**: When making a full-attack action, the wielder of a *speed weapon* may make one extra attack with it. The attack uses the wielder's full base attack bonus, plus any modifiers appropriate to the situation. (This benefit is not cumulative with similar effects, such as a *haste* spell.)

"Similar effects" includes other Speed weapons. (Also, blessings of fervor, dance of a thousand cuts, boots of haste, etc.)