# Many weapons with speed enhancement

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

**How many extra attacks does having multiple weapons with speed enhancement can be made?**

I have seen this question: [Do multiple Speed weapons grant multiple extra attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48366/do-multiple-speed-weapons-grant-multiple-extra-attacks)

However I don't know how is it in D&d 3.5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> (This benefit is not cumulative with similar effects, such as a *haste* spell.)

This line defines *speed* as “similar to” *haste*, and states that things “similar to” *haste* do not stack with it. Since it is, itself, similar to *haste*, it doesn’t stack with itself. Two *speed* weapons still only allow you one extra attack, it just means you get to choose which one you want to make that extra attack with.